# HTML + CSS Thumbnail help - Positioning the thumbnail only

Tags: html, css, positioning, thumbnails

So basiclly I'm trying to add a custom thumbnail on my website. I'm using the `<ol>` and styling it in css such as..

```
ol {
    counter-reset: none;         
    margin: 0px;         
    padding: 0px;       
    list-style-image: url('{image:thumbNail}');      
    position: relative;     
    right: 20px;     
}
```

But i want to position this without affecting my other text within the `<ol>`. how can i achieve this so i dont effect the text but just positon the thumbnail? Help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Dont use `list-style-image`, put a `padding-left` on `<li>` and put this image as `background-image` of <`li>`. The `list-style-image` is not so flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/enn5r/

```
<ol class="thumnails">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

---

```
ol.thumbnails li{
  padding:5px 0px 5px 25px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;
  background:transparent url(/icons/clock.png) no-repeat 5px 7px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I have had this problem for a while and gave up but found this website and now its sorted. Much appreciation!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `position:relative;` to `ol` list and give it `position:absolute;` and align it using `left` and `top` CSS attributes. But this all will work properly if the parent tag of `ol` has `position:relative;` applied. You can also get it to work using `position:relative;` but that wont be the proper way as it would shift the elements on different screen resolutions.